# Calculating vertex weights via mutually tangent circles of triangles

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, combinatorial-optimization, heuristics

given a metric graph with positive edge weights $\left|e_{ij}\right|$ a standard task, especially in the context of the Traveling Salesman Problem, is to calculate $\max\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\omega_i:\ \omega_i,\omega_j\ge0\,\land\, \omega_i+\omega_j\le\left|e_{ij}\right|$

**Question:**
what is known about the quality of the heuristic of calculating the $\omega_i$ from mutually tangent circles of triangles that are centered at the corners, that naturally appear in e.g. [Apollonian gaskets](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ApollonianGasket.html) and in the construction of [Soddy circles](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SoddyCircles.html)?
The radii of the mutually tangent circles of a triangle can be calculated in $O(1)$ time via a system of linear equations $r_A+r_B=c,\quad r_B+r_C=a,\quad r_C+r_A=b\quad $ with the solution $\quad 2r_A=c-a+b,\quad 2r_B=c+a-b,\quad 2r_C=-c+a+b$; iterating over all triangles yields a set of circles for each vertex of which the radius of smallest is chosen as the vertex weight.
In the planar euclidean case iterating over the triangles of a Delaunay triangulation would bring about further speedup to $O(n\log n)$ instead of $O(n^3)$
is the potential loss of optimality an acceptable tradein for simplicty and performance, given that many of the calculations can be carried out in parallel?

David Eppstein's paper "Maximizing the sum of radii of disjoint balls or disks", J. Computational Geometry 8 (1): 316–339, 2017, http://doi.org/10.20382/jocg.v8i1a12 contains efficient algorithms for fing the optimal vertex weights